I need help returning a 202 status before the NotificationToProcess call finishes its work
I need help returning a 202 status before the NotificationToProcess call finishes its work and this call also needs to trigger another call, DownloadNotification. I want NotificationToProcess to return immediately and let DownloadNotification complete its task in the background. How can I achieve this? I've attached the code below. It's not complete code.
[HttpPost("Endpoint")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status202Accepted)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SavePostedDocumentFromClient(
         
         [FromBody] NotificationToProcess.Command command = null)
        {


            if (command == null)
            {
                Logger.Warn("Validation Error: Command body is required.");
                
            }

            
            var response = Accepted();
            await _mediator.Send(command);
            return response;
        }

 public static class NotificationToProcess
    {
        public class Command : IRequest<bool>
        {
            
            public List<ObjectNotification> Value { get; set; }
        }


        public class Handler : IRequestHandler<Command, bool>
        {
            
            private readonly IMediator _mediator;

            public Handler(IMediator mediator)
            {
                
                _mediator = mediator;

            }
            public async Task<bool> Handle(Command request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                

                    Task.Run(() =>
                                    _mediator.Send(new DownloadNotification .Command
                                    {
                                       AgencyId = agencyId,
                                       LocationId = locationId,
                                       DocumentId = resourceId,
                                       Username = username,
                                       Password = password
                                    })
                                 );

                }

                return true;
            }

        }

I tried to use async and await but nothing is working.
